# I have to call multiple webpages to extract information for a django application and then display it but I don't know how to display properly

Tags: python, html, django, loops, view

My issue is that when I have called an external webpage and displayed as {{ html }} in the for loop it prints for all of them is there a way to print just for one. The part after b'{"carpark_name": "multi-storey", "date": "01-11-21 12:46:55", "spaces_available": 332}'
[this is the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgEYl.png)

This is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Carpark, Campus
from urllib.request import urlopen
def index(request):
    campus_list = Campus.objects.all()
    carpark_list = Carpark.objects.all()
    noparking = Campus.objects.filter(carpark=None)
    html = urlopen("https://mbezbradica.pythonanywhere.com/carparks/multi-storey").read()
    context = {'carpark_list': carpark_list,
               'campus_list': campus_list,
               'noparking': noparking,
               'html' : html
            }


    return render(request, "parkatdcu/index.html", context)
```

And this is my index.html code

```
<h1>Welcome to ParkAtDCU</h1>
   {% for campus in campus_list %}
     <h2>
       {{ campus }}
     </h2>
     {% if campus in noparking %}
        No carparks found
     {% else %}
        <ul>
        {% for carpark in carpark_list %}
           {% if campus == carpark.campus_id %}
              <li> {{ carpark.name }}: {{ carpark.spaces}} spaces, {{carpark.disabled_spaces}} spaces for people with disabilities, {{ html }}</li>
           {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {{ url }}
        </ul>
      {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I am trying to print the spaces available to each individual carpark

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting is a bytes object, you can decode it into a string object and use `ast.literal_eval()` to convert it into a dictionary. And then pass that dictionary into the template. Honestly this is a JSON object and you should not call it HTML. I'll give it the name `data` here. And then in the template just call whatever you can want to show:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Carpark, Campus
from urllib.request import urlopen
import ast
def index(request):
    campus_list = Campus.objects.all()
    carpark_list = Carpark.objects.all()
    noparking = Campus.objects.filter(carpark=None)
    html = urlopen("https://mbezbradica.pythonanywhere.com/carparks/multi-storey").read()
    data_string = html.decode("utf-8")
    data = ast.literal_eval(test_string)
    context = {'carpark_list': carpark_list,
               'campus_list': campus_list,
               'noparking': noparking,
               'html' : data
            }


    return render(request, "parkatdcu/index.html", context)
```

And in your html file:

```
<h1>Welcome to ParkAtDCU</h1>
   {% for campus in campus_list %}
     <h2>
       {{ campus }}
     </h2>
     {% if campus in noparking %}
        No carparks found
     {% else %}
        <ul>
        {% for carpark in carpark_list %}
           {% if campus == carpark.campus_id %}
              <li> {{ carpark.name }}: {{ carpark.spaces}} spaces, {{carpark.disabled_spaces}} spaces for people with disabilities, car park name: {{ html.carpark_name }}</li>
           {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {{ url }}
        </ul>
      {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

But the way you are doing it is very dirty (in my opinion). I suggest you install `requests` and use `requests.get(url).json()` it will give you a dictionary without going through this hassle, making you code cleaner (again, in my opinion).
You can install `requests`:

`pip install requests`

and do this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Carpark, Campus
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests
def index(request):
    campus_list = Campus.objects.all()
    carpark_list = Carpark.objects.all()
    noparking = Campus.objects.filter(carpark=None)
    data = requests.get("https://mbezbradica.pythonanywhere.com/carparks/multi-storey").json()
    context = {'carpark_list': carpark_list,
               'campus_list': campus_list,
               'noparking': noparking,
               'html' : data
            }


    return render(request, "parkatdcu/index.html", context)
```

(I didn't change your html context variable because "if it works, don't touch it", I suggest you change your context variable name "html" to "data" or something like that).